# Bluetooth adapter not found in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, laptop, bluetooth, hp

I recently switched from Windows to Ubuntu 14.04 and now it seems that my hp-1000 notebook computer can not find the Bluetooth adapter anymore. I even used it right before I switched to Ubuntu from Windows 8 on the same device.

What can I do be able to use my Bluetooth adapter again?

Comment: Probably you want to research the specific hardware to make sure it's supported. Try the 'lspci' command for built-in hardware and 'lsusb' for USB external stuff. Check the man pages for the nifty switches you can throw on these to get more info.  Also search the repositories for tools that might help you get it working. Looking through Synaptic, I see packages with names like blueman, bluetooth and gnome-bluetooth. So maybe it's just not installed.

Comment: Please add the results from terminal command `lsusb` to your question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you have a dual-boot system. I am using such a system too on my ASUS N56VZ. Thus I know you have to be careful not to disable your BT adapter when working with Windows. You can check if your Bluetooth adapter is enabled or disabled by using the Bluetooth widget offered by Ubuntu. However, for enabling Bluetooth I first have to open this widget via the start menu, then I have to close it and finally I have to click on the Bluetooth symbol in the tray in the right corner.

Alternatively, you (at least I) can run the command "bluetooth" in a terminal (open with Ctrl + Alt + T or by simply searching for terminal). Here is an example:

```
lukas@LUKAS-LAPTOP0-0:~$ bluetooth
bluetooth = off (software)

lukas@LUKAS-LAPTOP0-0:~$ bluetooth on
bluetooth = on

lukas@LUKAS-LAPTOP0-0:~$ bluetooth
bluetooth = on
```

bluetooth without any parameters queries the state of the Bluetooth adapter and bluetooth on turns it on.

Comment: You could add it to your startup programs to avoid much of that or create a *.desktop file you can just click.

Comment: tnx for the advice but unfortunately I'm not using dual-boot system.